# How to use Alamofire with iOS Widget

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

When implementing Alamofire in my Widgets target it says eg "Use of unresolved identifier 'Alamofire'. Somehow I need to add my Widget as a target for the Alamofire project. How can I achieve this?

Some example code:

```
// Parameters
let parameters: [String : Any] = [
    "id": id,
    "state": true
]

Alamofire.request("https://someurl.com" method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

    // Check if the request was successful
    if (response.result.isSuccess) {
        let statusCode = response.response!.statusCode
        if (statusCode == 200) {

        } else {

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have built a few today extensions, and this is how I install Alamofire. Your widget is another project, along with the main application that runs the widget, in your workspace. So you need to install Alamofire in one (or both, depending on your needs). Change your podfile to:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target "MainAPP" do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod ‘SwiftyJSON’
end
target "Widget" do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod ‘SwiftyJSON’
end
```

EDIT: If you add it manually, just go to Project -> General -> Linked frameworks and libraries, and add the Alamofire xcode project as a dependency

Comment: I installed Alamofire manually. Is there any way to apply it on the Widget manually as well?

Comment: @DanielTovesson Then, go to your Project -> General -> Linked frameworks and libraries, and add the Alamofire xcode project as a dependency

Comment: Ah, I made the silly mistake not importing the Alamofire framework in the new file with the Target Membership set to "Widget" (import Alamofire). But I'll accept your answer as it answered the question!

Comment: @DanielTovesson Thank you! Just edited my answer with the manual alternative, so that the people who has the same mistake can get the answer quickier. And don't worry, I made that mistake a lot of times haha